# How do ggplot and plot handle inf values differently?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am struggling to understand why `ggplot` and `plot` are producing slightly different plots of the same data. `ggplot` is including inf values up top, while `plot` isn't.

```
with(geneFDR, plot(log2(FC), -log10(FDR), pch=20, main="FDR vs. Real FC",
col=geneFDR$FDRColor))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data=geneFDR, aes(x=log2(FC), y=-log10(FDR), color=FDRFCthreshold)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.4, size=1.75) +
  ggtitle("FDR vs. Real Fold Change") +
  xlab("log2 Real Fold Change") + ylab("-log10(FDR)")
```

[image]

Source of inf values:

```
min(geneFDR$FDR)
[1] 0
max(geneFDR$FDR)
[1] 0.009883703

min(-log10(geneFDR$FDR))
[1] 2.00508
max(-log10(geneFDR$FDR))
[1] Inf
```

How is the default `plot` function handling inf values differently than `ggplot`?

Comment: A simpler reproducible example: `x <- c(0,1,2,Inf)` then `plot(x)` and `ggplot(data.frame(x),aes(x=1:4,y=x)) + geom_point()`

Comment: It appears that `ggplot` considers the upper and lower boundaries of the plot (which lie outside of the axis limits) to be `Inf` and `-Inf`, respectively, whereas `plot` simply ignores `Inf` by default.

Comment: This seems like a dubious design choice, given that you can end up with things like `ggplot(data.frame(x),aes(x=1:4,y=x)) + geom_line()` which suggest an entirely different angle than what the data would actually represent.

Comment: Indeed, it is not an aspect of `ggplot2` that I've considered until now. I suppose the assumption is that `Inf` values would normally be removed or ideally, not be generated.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
scale_y_continuous(oob=scales::discard)
```