# ggplotly doesn't show bars with infinte values

Tags: r

I am trying to do barplot using ggplotly when my data has Inf value in it.

That's my code:

```
table<-data.frame("X"=c("a","b","c","d","e"),"Y"=c(-1,0,1,2,Inf))
p <- ggplot(table, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +  
  labs(x="X",y="Y") + geom_bar(stat="identity") +  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = table$X[order(table$Y)]) 
p<-p+theme(
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
  panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightgray"),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill="white")
) 
p
ggplotly(p)
```

Is there anyway to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: How would you like to see infinity displayed on your chart?

Comment: The same like how it's shown in ggplot which is p in my code script

Comment: Draw and infinite bar by hand and get back with us.

Answer (score 1):

ggplot shows infinite values at the max range of the plot, while base R `plot` and `plotly` throw out non-finite values. One approach (the only?) would be to manipulate your data to convert infinite values to a finite value and adjust the ggplot `expand` term in `scale_y_continuous` to match the original plot.

[How do ggplot and plot handle inf values differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271442/how-do-ggplot-and-plot-handle-inf-values-differently)

```
table_max = max(table$Y[is.finite(table$Y)]) * 1.08 # Default ggplot padding beyond finite 
#  values; I thought 1.05 would work, but 1.08 empirically looks closer in this case
table2 <- table
table2$Y <- ifelse(table2$Y > table_max, table_max, table$Y)

p2 <- ggplot(table2, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +  
  labs(x="X",y="Y") + geom_bar(stat="identity") +  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = table$X[order(table$Y)])  +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.05, 0)))
p2 <- p2+theme(
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
  panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightgray"),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill="white")
) 
p2

plotly::ggplotly(p2)
```

Comment: I made a little change to your code so the plot will show me the right tooltip.
I kept the original Y under the name Value and added it to the aes in ggplot

table2 <- table

table2$Value<-table2$Y

table2$Y <- ifelse(table2$Y > table_max, table_max, table$Y)
                                                                                        
p2<-ggplot(table2, aes(x=X, y=Y,value=Value))+...

plotly::ggplotly(p2,tooltip = c("x", "value"))